# Discovering whether any value in an array matches a given value

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want this function to compare strings from a structure and return `indice = 0` if there are equal strings OR `indice = -1` if there aren't any strings = `matriculaInserida`.

But it isn't working.

```
int pesquisaMatricula(char matriculaInserida[MAXMATRICULA], tVeiculo estruturaPrincipal[MAXVEICULOS], int numVeiculosRegistados){
int i, indice;

    for (i = 0 ; i <= numVeiculosRegistados ; i++){
        if ((strcmp(estruturaPrincipal[i].matricula, matriculaInserida) != 0)){
            indice = -1;
        }
        else{
            indice = 0;
        }
    }
    return indice;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error? Or is the output just wrong?

Comment: `i` should go from 0 to `numVeiculosRegistados - 1`

Comment: songyuanyao is correct.  As the code is now, the `for` loop completes, and the value of `indice` reflects only the last comparison, likely hiding a previous, successful "hit".

Comment: Expanding on a point made correctly by [donjuedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2565958/donjuedo) in a terse [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876149/comparing-strings-c#comment55516137_33876149), in C, a loop that runs over all the elements of an array is normally written `for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)` with a less than `<` operator. The code in the question has `<=` instead. It can't be stated definitively that it is wrong (we can't see the calling code), but it is extremely likely to be wrong.  Use the idiom I showed to avoid accessing arrays out of bounds.

Comment: this is a runtime question.  It needs 1) actual code that cleanly compiles, 2) the input data, 3) the expected output 4) the actual output

Answer (score 5):

You should `return 0` immediately once you find equal string, and then `return -1` if can't find any equal strings at last. Otherwise the result of comparing will be overwritten again and again, and the comparison's result of last time will be returned, always.

```
int pesquisaMatricula(char matriculaInserida[MAXMATRICULA], tVeiculo estruturaPrincipal[MAXVEICULOS], int numVeiculosRegistados) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= numVeiculosRegistados; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(estruturaPrincipal[i].matricula, matriculaInserida) == 0)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop as long as no match had been found, then indicate success and break the loop.

```
int pesquisaMatricula(
  char matriculaInserida[MAXMATRICULA], 
  tVeiculo estruturaPrincipal[MAXVEICULOS], 
  size_t numVeiculosRegistados) 
{
  int result = -1; /* Be pessimistic. */

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numVeiculosRegistados; ++i) 
  {
    if (0 == strcmp(estruturaPrincipal[i].matricula, matriculaInserida)) 
    {
      result = 0; /* Indicate success ... */
      break; /* ... and leave. */
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```